# Make horizontal 'li' the same height in CSS and HTML

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, height, html-lists

I am trying to create `ul` with 2 `li`s, and they will be set horizontally. Here how it's looking right now:

[image]

As you can see the left's `li` height is less than the right one. I would like that the left one is same as the right one. Also I am using [Bootstrap](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bootstrap_%28front-end_framework%29) on this website. Here is my code:

```
<ul class="thumbnails <?php echo $pageLang; ?>">
    <li class="span6" >
        <div class="commentsArea">
            <h3>dsfdsfd</h3>
            <p></p>
        </div>
    </li>
    <li class="span6 <?php echo $pageLang;?>">
        <label>Name</label>
        <input type="text" class="span6">
        <label>Description:</label>
        <textarea class="span6" rows="5" maxlength="450"></textarea>
        <button class="btn btn-success" value="button">
    </li>
</ul>
```

Relevant CSS:

```
.commentsArea {
    background-color: #D4E7ED;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    -webkit-border-radius: 10px 5px 5px 10px;
    border-radius: 10px 5px 5px 10px;
    -moz-border-radius: 10px 5px 5px 10px;
    padding: 5px;
}
```

I tried to set `commentsArea` height to 100%, but it didn't help. Also if I set the left `li` height "hard coded" (for example, height=228px) it works fine.

Is there a way to make (1) and (2) the same height?

Comment: Did you try .span6{height: 100%;} ?

Comment: I have tried: `<li class="span6" style="height: 100%">` and it didn't work.

Comment: Have you tried putting a containing `div` around the `ul`?

Comment: tried and it didn't help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can use a fixed height, add the below CSS

```
.thumnails li {
    height: 228px;
}
```

Or whatever height is required.

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend you not to use `ul` and `li` for such a markup. It's pretty easy to accomplish using `divs`. In fact it does not look like a proper usage of lists.

```
<div class="thumbnails thumbnails-cont">
    <div class="span4 comments-cont">
        <div class="commentsArea">
            <h3>dsfdsfd</h3>
            <p></p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="span4 offset4">
        <label>Name</label>
        <input type="text" class="span6">
        <label>Description:</label>
        <textarea class="span6" rows="5" maxlength="450"></textarea>
        <button class="btn btn-success" value="button">Test</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.thumbnails-cont {
    position: relative;
}
.comments-cont {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/n2VGS/

Comment: because I am using boot strap, the solution you have provided it messes my page up. thanks for the help. I hope it is still possible with the `ul` and `li` tags.

Comment: This is strange. Anyway you can still use ul and li the same way: http://jsfiddle.net/n2VGS/1/

Comment: Now it is getting on top one of each other

Comment: I think I just add the height with javascript and Jquery.

Comment: *Now it is getting on top one of each other*. Because left `li` is absolutely positioned. You need to set a `margin-left` for the right `li`.

Comment: There's nothing special about divs that makes it easier than lists:  anything divs can do, lists can do too.  I do agree, however, that this is an improper use of lists.